# Nested Query Update

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get this to run (took me while to figure out) but it seems i need a nested query for the update to work and im blanking out. Any tips/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
update `deal_change_log`
set new_value = 'Paying' and old_value = 'Null'
where id in (select item_id from deal_change_log
             where field_key = '458a901560dc06efb78fe365b951dacd3a6a1a11' 
             and `old_value` = 'billing details entered' 
             and `new_value` = 'paying'
             and item_id not in (select item_id from `deal_change_log` d2 where d2.`field_key` = '458a901560dc06efb78fe365b951dacd3a6a1a11' 
             and d2.`log_time` > `log_time`) 
order by item_id);
```

Comment: Add/Tag DBMS server

Comment: share some sample data,

Comment: Don't store the text NULL for NULL, i.e. do `old_value = Null`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

use alias,

```
update `deal_change_log`
set new_value = 'Paying' and old_value = 'Null'
where id in (select item_id from deal_change_log d1
             where d1.field_key = '458a901560dc06efb78fe365b951dacd3a6a1a11' 
             and d1.`old_value` = 'billing details entered' 
             and d1.`new_value` = 'paying'
             and d1.item_id not in (select item_id from `deal_change_log` d2 where d2.`field_key` = '458a901560dc06efb78fe365b951dacd3a6a1a11' 
             and d2.`log_time` > d1.`log_time`) 
order by d1.item_id);
```

Comment: None are working - i get a 'You can't specify target table 'deal_change_log' for update in FROM clause'. Im running MySQL version 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid use a subquery, because can make slow execute:

```
  declare @item_id2 varchar(100)
  select @item_id2 =item_id  from `deal_change_log` d2 
          where d2.`field_key` = '458a901560dc06efb78fe365b951dacd3a6a1a11' 
         and d2.`log_time` > `log_time`) order by item_id
  declare @item_id varchar(100)
   select @item_id= item_id  from deal_change_log
         where field_key = '458a901560dc06efb78fe365b951dacd3a6a1a11' 
         and `old_value` = 'billing details entered' 
         and `new_value` = 'paying'
         and item_id not in ( @item_id2)

  update `deal_change_log`
  set new_value = 'Paying' and old_value = 'Null'
   where id in ( @item_id) ;
```